# NameError: uninitialized constant custom job file Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a file **app/jobs/foo_bar_job.rb** with the following:

```
class FooBarJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    # Do stuff
  end
end
```

I run `rails c` to open up the rails console and I get the following when I type `FooBarJob`

> NameError: uninitialized constant FooBarJob

My app doesn't know about the constant.  I'm not sure what I am missing. I also attempted putting the following within **config/application.rb** but it didn't fix it either:

```
require_relative 'boot'
require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.load_defaults 6.0
    # I added this line to attempt to load all files within /app/jobs
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'jobs', '{**}')]
  end
end
```

Comment: have you exited and restarted `rails console` and then try again?

Comment: @Masroor wow, so that did it. My environment: I'm using vagrant to run a linux VM, and on my host machine I'm using rubymine.  Somewhere: something must've not gotten picked up.  I restarted the VM, and it now finds the constant.

Comment: normally it should have worked on just restarting the `rails console`, not sure why it worked only after restarting the VM itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a very environment-specific issue. I'll post my fix, but it is still a mystery.

I am using vagrant to run a linux VM on my host machine, and on my host machine I am using rubymine.

The rails app lives within a shared directory between the host and vagrant vm.

For whatever reason: running `rails c` was not picking up the existence of that job file.  Once I rebooted the vm: it worked as expected.